# Error with building Android NDK Project

Tags: android, eclipse, android-ndk, cygwin

I wand build project in windows, I get same Errors:

```
   bash C:\linux\android-ndk1\ndk-build V=1 
    cygwin warning:
      MS-DOS style path detected: C:\dev\android\workspace4_android\FFWall
      Preferred POSIX equivalent is: /cygdrive/c/dev/android/workspace4_android/FFWall
      CYGWIN environment variable option "nodosfilewarning" turns off this warning.
      Consult the user's guide for more details about POSIX paths:
        http://cygwin.com/cygwin-ug-net/using.html#using-pathnames
    Android NDK: ERROR:jni/Android.mk:bambuser-libavcore: LOCAL_SRC_FILES points to a missing file    
    /cygdrive/c/linux/android-ndk1/build/core/prebuilt-library.mk:43: *** Android NDK: Aborting    .  Stop.
    Android NDK: Check that jni/ffmpeg-android/build/ffmpeg/armeabi/lib/libavcore.so exists  or that its path is correct
```

Another way building:

```
C:\art\android-ndk\ndk-build V=1 

Cannot run program "C:\art\android-ndk\ndk-build": Launching failed
Error: Program "C:/art/android-ndk/ndk-build" is not found in PATH

PATH=[C:\Art\android-ndk;C:/Program Files/Java/jre7/bin/client;C:/Program Files/Java/jre7/bin;C:/Program Files/Java/jre7/lib/i386;C:\Program Files\PC Connectivity Solution\;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2011a\runtime\win32;C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2011a\bin;C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2007b\bin;C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2007b\bin\win3;C:\dev\android\android-sdk-windows\tools;C:\cygwin\bin;C:/art/android-ndk/;C:\linux\android-ndk-r7b;C:\dev\android\eclipse]
```

Why this happened?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From: http://developer.android.com/sdk/ndk/overview.html#reqs

Required development tools

- For all development platforms, GNU Make 3.81 or later is required.    Earlier versions of GNU Make might work but have not been tested.
- A recent version of awk (either GNU Awk or Nawk) is also required.
- **For Windows, Cygwin 1.7 or higher is required. The NDK will not work    with Cygwin 1.5 installations.**

Meaning, that you will have to install Cygwin. After that you can call the ndk-build like:

```
$ProjectPath> /cygdrive/c/myNdkPath/ndk-build
```

Please also check the "Getting Started" part of:

http://developer.android.com/sdk/ndk/index.html